# Migrate from Paperclip to Carrierwave or Refile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, paperclip, carrierwave

I would like to migrate from Paperclip to Carrier Wave or Refile because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198602/not-losing-paperclip-attachment-when-model-cannot-be-saved-due-to-validation-err).  The solution written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680484/how-to-persist-file-upload-fields-after-a-rails-validation-error) is impressive, but strikes me as complex and perhaps brittle.

My Rails4 app has 100's of images in production that were uploaded with Paperclip.  Files are stored on production server. I have looked for a complete set of steps to follow to migrate, but keep coming up empty.

Is there a set of steps one can follow that allows for migration without necessitating application code re-write?

Alternatively, is there another way to persist uploaded files in Paperclip when form validation fails?

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

Tried the solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680484/how-to-persist-file-upload-fields-after-a-rails-validation-error) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/646389/galatians .  My paperclip :path and :url interpolations make use of :id_partition.  I don't see a way this can be reconciled with an uploaded Image that is staged, but not yet saved.

Answer (score 1):

I migrated to Carrierwave.  Here are the relevant stats:

- Time to work on and fail at coding a solution for persistent files
  across form reloading with Paperclip - **4 hours.**  See OP update for the issue I could not overcome.
- Time to Migrate to carrierwave, adjust the relevant models, controllers, and forms, and test. - **2 hours.**  Not so bad.

This key info helped me adjust the paths correctly.  Keeping the path identical was important to me for avoiding having to move images to a new location in production:

- Carrierwave code for generating paperclip-like :path and :url info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Compatibility/Paperclip).
- Paperclip interpolation info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/4.3.6/Paperclip/Interpolations).
- This [link](http://www.bwigg.com/2009/10/paperclip-customizing-paths-and-urls/) got me on the right track, although my default :path made use of :id_partition not :id.

UPDATE:
Migration breaks this paradigm:

```
  @protocol.images.each do |i|  
    tmp=i.dup  
    tmp.avatar = File.open(i.avatar.current_path)  
    tmp.save!  
    @dest.images << tmp          
  end
```

See: [Duplicating a record that contains a carrierwave avatar : Getting "can't convert nil into Integer" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192981/duplicating-a-record-that-contains-a-carrierwave-avatar-getting-cant-convert/39193801#39193801)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything because the only data needed to get images is already stored in DB.

Comment: Well, there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449069/wrong-url-with-migrating-paperclip-to-carrierwave  and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640866/rails-convert-paperclip-directory-structure-to-carrierwave ... to wonder about.  Have seen others with unexpected outcome.